# Can the CONCATENATE formula be used in place of the ampersand?

Tags: vba, excel, date

SITUATION

I have generated a series of 52 date serial numbers:-
42831 to 43195 in cells B3 to BB3 respectively (each date serial number incremented by 7).

The following code converts the date serial numbers to dates in the format "dd-mmm-yy". Here is the code which displays 52 invoice dates for each week of the year from 06-Apr-17 to 05-Apr-18 in the next row down:-

```
Dim intAdd7 As Integer
intAdd7 = 0
Dim i As Integer
Dim lngSerialDate As Long
    For i = 2 To 54  'COL C TO COL BB
        lngSerialDate = Cells(3, i).Value + intAdd7
        Cells(4, i) = "=TEXT(" & lngSerialDate + intAdd7 & ",""dd-mmm-yy"")"
    Next i
End Sub
```

I must add at this point that Nekomatic kindly provided me with the placement of the ampersands.

OBJECTIVE

Being a relative newbie to the VBA language, I'm led to believe that the ampersand acts as a concatenation operator. I'm being academic here and trying to learn the ins and outs of the language but am having no success in  substituting the CONCATENATE formula as an alternative to the ampersand. Here are my attempts:-

```
Cells(4, i) = "=TEXT(CONCATENATE("lngSerialDate+intAdd7,")""dd-mmm-yy"")"

Cells(4, i) = "=TEXT(CONCATENATE("lngSerialDate+intAdd7",)""dd-mmm-yy"")"

Cells(4, i) = "=TEXT(CONCATENATE("lngSerialDate+intAdd7",),""dd-mmm-yy"")"
```

All three attempts makes VBA bark at me to give a Compile error:-Expected-End of statement  and the text turns red and the variable "lngSerialDate" gets highlighted in blue.

Does VBA not allow the TEXT and CONCATENATE to operate together or is my syntax wrong? Any help out there would be much appreciated.

ComfortablyNumb

Comment: The ampersand as used in the original code block doesn't literally replace each ampersand with a `CONCATENATE` function. Instead, it joins (concatenates) each segment of the string with the corresponding variable. The end result is a string that looks like: `=TEXT(42831,"dd-mm-yyyy"`. In the version that you're trying to right, you're trying to use the `Concatenate` function in an Excel formula, which just won't work.

Comment: You're mixing a format with a sum, no?  If I read it correctly, are you trying to do this: `=TEXT(CONCATENATE(" &lngSerialDate+intAdd7&","dd-mmm-yy"),"dd-mmm-yy")`.  You have a value, but then a format, which is fine, but you don't specify the format for the `Text()` part of your formula.  What is your actual goal in using CONCATENATE?

Comment: your syntax is wrong. At many places. VBA variable can't be used in worksheet formula as named range. For Text formula you are missing comma for format parameter and have extra quotes. Either use worksheet function `Concat` or use named ranges intead of variables. Also correct way to set formula is `.Formula`

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to write formulas into the cells?  Why not just write the dates directly?

Comment: @Comintern Hi, It was an academic challenge only. I'm endeavouring to learn as much as possible(being self-taught). No other reason really.

Comment: @BruceWayne Hi, My goal was to incorporate the CONCATENATE function somehow in place of the & operator which, I am led to believe, does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

In your original code, the ampersand is being used as a VBA concatenation operator.  The `CONCAT` or `CONCATENATE` functions are Excel worksheet functions.   `Concat` is also a member of the VBA WorksheetFunction object, so the equivalent, in VBA would be something like:

```
Cells(4, i) = WorksheetFunction.Concat("=TEXT(", lngSerialDate + intAdd7, ",""dd-mmm-yy"")"
```

or, with each segment broken out:

```
Cells(5, i) = WorksheetFunction.Concat( _
        "=TEXT(", _
        lngSerialDate + intAdd7, _
        ",""dd-mmm-yy"")")
```

Of course, one disadvantage is the limitation as to the number of arguments allowed for the function.  Also, as pointed out by Comintern, it might be simpler to just write the date to the cell instead of a formula.

Comment: Thank you, Ron Rosenfeld. At least I'm not getting a compile error!! However, the Run-time error '438'-'Object doesn't support this property or method' is indicating that the Concat method is not supported by the Worksheet object-that's what I've deduced from my limited experience!!! Also the drop down menu which appears after entering the period after 'WorksheetFunction' does not display 'Concat'. BTW I'm running excel2007. Is there a way round this please?

Comment: @ComfortablyNumb `Concat` was not introduced until later. If `Concatenate` is not there in `2007` then just go back to using your `&` operator.  Using a WorksheetFunction in place of a native VBA operator adds inefficiency (as does writing this formula where you could just directly write the date).

Comment: Many thanks for the quick response. I was just getting into an academic challenge!! It's one way of broadening my knowledge!!